# Google 2-step verification - AngularJS - Automation failing

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am automating a web portal using AngularJS with protractor which uses google 2 step verification after you click on login. The 2 step verification sends a text message to the text phone we are using.

My Scripts are failing in the 2 step verification process as it requires manual intervention. This is a must to have and cannot remove it. How can one work around this 2 step verification process? If anyone knows, Please let me know.

Comment: what do you mean by "manual intervention"? What exactly fails?

Comment: that security code needs to be entered in the web portal in order for the web bale to load with the content. That's where it is failing. If i am manually testing the portal, I can see what is the security code i am getting in the test device and enter it manually in order for me to access the web page.

Comment: old but good question, I am stuck on the same problem now, I need to wait for an email and enter a code manually when I receive it. Needless to say this is very annoying, automated testing should not require me to enter a pin code every time, but I haven't figured out a way to overcome this problem.
did you find a solution?

Comment: I disabled the 2 step verification in settings...Only my credential had the ability to disable... Sorry, I don't have a solution.

Comment: Another issue is google requires authentication when logging in various devices (eg. VMs, or Sauce), which kills automation. Is there a way to add an email to the security DMZ?